# chrome extension message passsing: sendResponse is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I'm trying to exchange data between an internal web page of the extension `chrome-extension://myExtensionId/path/to/web/page.html` and content scripts.

So, in order to make this data persistent among different content scripts, I'm trying to save it as **global variables** in the extension's background! I do so using message passing.

#### My problem is:

When I try to send a response back from the background I get this error:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: sendResponse is not a
>   function

I followed the [documentation's examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and this is my attempt:

#### In the `scriptOfTheInternalPage.js` :

```
var message = {
    'order': 'setData',
    'varName': 'myArray',
    'data': myArray
};
extPort.postMessage(message, function (response) {
    console.log('response:\n', JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

#### In `background.js` :

```
var globals = {
    'myArray': [],
    ...
};
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(
            function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
                console.log(
                        'the port received this message:\n', JSON.stringify(message), '\n',
                        (sender.tab) ? ' from tab #' + sender.tab.id : ' from the extension!'
                        );
                if (message.order === 'setData') {
                    globals[message.varName] = message.data;
                    sendResponse({'response': 'data saved!'}); //<=====
                }
                return true; //<=== tried to return true here as well;
            });
});
```

Does this error means I should create a brand new function outside of the `onMessage` event listener?

I'm confused! What am I missing?

Comment: **all** the examples of `port.onMessage.addListener` are like `port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {` - not a single one has `function (message, sender, sendResponse) {` as the callback "pattern" - you are using the callback pattern as described for `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port's `onMessage` event listeners do not have the same signature as `runtime.onMessage`. You don't get `sender` and `sendResponse` parameters, only the message. Returning `true` has no effect either.

To reply to a message, you need to use the port itself. This is [covered by examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect):

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
    port.postMessage({question: "Who's there?"});
}
```

So you do need an `onMessage` listener on both sides, and some way to track requests (unique ID?) if several can be made.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! this was confusing!